# Send Mail from Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

i'm following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview#Sending_Mail_with_the_JavaMail_API) to send Email from app engine.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    String msgBody = "...";
    try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myAppAdmin@gmail.com"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress("AnotherMailOfMine@gmail.com"));
        msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
        msg.setText(msgBody);
        Transport.send(msg);

    } catch (AddressException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // ...
    }
```

However  i obtain this error

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract    java.lang.Boolean net.adeptus.client.util.UtilService.sendMailActivation(net.adeptus.client.DTO.PlayerDTO)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/TraceOutputStream
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at
```

i've checked that i'm not using Oracle jar and that mail sender exists.

Any idea?

Comment: The error says that you have some error in GWT as your code for sending mail is absolutely fine. You are missing some jar.

Comment: do you know which jar is needed inside sdk? if i check in eclipse every include points to a class.

Comment: i'm so dumb! i'd forgotten to delete imap.jar. Now is all fine. The issue was that i had some jar MORE. thanks

Answer (score -1):

This error means that such Class definition was found at compiled time but is not found at runtime.

Try adding the JavaMail api file into your LIB folder.

*(I personally use the 1.4.1 version. (http://download.java.net/maven/1/javax.mail/jars/))*

hope this helps

Comment: on tutorial is written that all libs are included into SDK. If i add that library the problem isn't solved.

Comment: oracle jars are not needed.